# Create table in SAS

Tags: sas

I have to create a table in SAS from these inputs.

```
la grande vadrouille Louis de Funès 16 1966 A V 7
le mur de l’atlantique Jean Poiret 14 1970 AB 6
le cercle rouge Alain Delon 20 1970 Z A 8
le corniaud Louis de Funès 14 1965 SD 4
le chanteur de mexico Luis Mariano 12 1956 A B 5
la traversée de Paris Jean Gabin 19 1958 S 2
```

This code gives me the right result, but I had to add spaces to make every value in each variable the same length.

```
DATA DMExo1.Q1;
INPUT Film  $CHAR22. Acteur $15. Note 39-40 Annee 41-45 Code $ 46-49 Ordre ;
CARDS;
la grande vadrouille   Louis de Funès 16 1966 A V 7
le mur de l’atlantique Jean Poiret    14 1970 AB  6
le cercle rouge        Alain Delon    20 1970 Z A 8
le corniaud            Louis de Funès 14 1965 SD  4
le chanteur de mexico  Luis Mariano   12 1956 A B 5
la traversée de Paris  Jean Gabin     19 1958 S   2
;RUN;
```

Is there a way to get that result, without changing the inputs? I have to use CARDS.
Thank you so much!

Putting spaces is the only thing that works for me so far. I don't know if my teacher allow us to change the inputs, so if I can find a better answer I'd love that

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to align the columns. You could just use a delimiter between the fields on the line.

So you could for example use | as the delimiter since it does not appear in the data.  But if the delimiter does appear in the data just add quotes around that value.  Make sure to add : modifier before any in-line informats in the INPUT statement so the lines are still read in LIST MODE.

```
data DMExo1.Q1;
  infile cards dsd dlm='|' truncover;
  input Film :$22. Acteur :$15. Note Annee Code :$5. Ordre ;
cards;
la grande vadrouille|Louis de Funès|16|1966|AV|7
le mur de l’atlantique|Jean Poiret|14|1970|AB|6
le cercle rouge|Alain Delon|20|1970|ZA|8
le corniaud|Louis de Funès|14|1965|SD|4
le chanteur de mexico|Luis Mariano|12|1956|AB|5
la traversée de Paris|Jean Gabin|19|1958|S|2
;
```

Answer (score 0):

As posted, because there is no obvious field delimiter, and as you state the layout is not fixed.  There is no simple way to just `INPUT` the columns.

You can parse the data using the supposition that the film name is always lower case and the actor name always starts with a capital letter.

Here is one way to parse using regular expressions.

```
data want ;
  length Film $22 Acteur $15 Note 8 Annee 8 Code $8  Ordre 8 ;

  rx = prxparse('m/^(.*?)\s+([A-Z].*?)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.+?)\s(\d+)/') ;

  input ;
  if prxmatch(rx, _infile_) then do ;
    Film   =       prxposn(rx,1,_infile_) ;
    Acteur =       prxposn(rx,2,_infile_) ;
    Note   = input(prxposn(rx,3,_infile_), best.) ;
    Annee  = input(prxposn(rx,4,_infile_), best.) ;
    Code   =       prxposn(rx,5,_infile_) ;
    Ordre  = input(prxposn(rx,6,_infile_), best.) ;
  end;
  else
    Acteur = 'Could not parse' ;

  drop rx ;
datalines ;
la grande vadrouille Louis de Funès 16 1966 A V 7
le mur de l’atlantique Jean Poiret 14 1970 AB 6
le cercle rouge Alain Delon 20 1970 Z A 8
le corniaud Louis de Funès 14 1965 SD 4
le chanteur de mexico Luis Mariano 12 1956 A B 5
la traversée de Paris Jean Gabin 19 1958 S 2
;
```

Someone else may show a way using held input `INPUT ... @`